# ASP image upload and Jcrop?

Tags: asp-classic, upload, jcrop

I upload images with aspsmartupload and it work as it should, good!
But after I have uploaded the image I would like to be able to crop the image with Jcrop.
I have managed to get the Jcrop script to work on a image(showing the crop rectangle on the image).

But how do I actually crop the image with ASP and the saving it?

I have found a lot of php scripts, but how to do it with ASP?
Any help really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to use an ASP compoenent that allows you to crop the image. Have a look at [AspJpeg](http://www.aspjpeg.com/manual_04.html#4_3)

The other options you have are to use .NET (which should run if your ASP pages are hosted on a windows machine)

Or use PHP like the [Jcrop example](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html)